# Corda White list Exception

Tags: corda

I tried to manually add "org.hibernate.AnnotationException" to the whitelist. I tried to implement serializationWhitelist interface in my state class.

lets say my state class is of type Person and has Address type defined inside it. Every time I try to get the states out of the vault I get this error. or another for "org.hibernate.MappingException". Also When my state implements QueryableState I'm not even able to persist the data. and get the below error

```
    Starting as webserver: localhost:10007
Webserver started up in 59.55 sec
>> Generating transaction based on new create.
>> Verifying contract constraints.
>> Signing transaction with our private key.
>> Gathering the counterparty's signature.
>> Structural step change in child of Gathering the counterparty's signature.
>> Collecting signatures from counter-parties.
>> Done
>> Obtaining notary signature and recording transaction.
>> Structural step change in child of Obtaining notary signature and recording transaction.
>> Requesting signature by notary service
[1;31mE 14:01:20+0530 [qtp9538928-76] controller.DMSController.create - com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Class org.hibernate.MappingException is not annotated or on the whitelist, so cannot be used in serialization
Serialization trace:
cause (rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException)
throwable (rx.Notification)
[m java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Class org.hibernate.MappingException is not annotated or on the whitelist, so cannot be used in serialization
Serialization trace:
cause (rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException)
throwable (rx.Notification)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl.get(CordaFutureImpl.kt) ~[corda-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at com.den.managment.controller.DMSController.create(DMSController.java:124) [DisputeManagmentSystem.jar:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) [jersey-common-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) [jersey-common-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) [jersey-common-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) [jersey-common-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) [jersey-common-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317) [jersey-common-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:845) [jetty-servlet-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583) [jetty-servlet-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1174) [jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511) [jetty-servlet-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1106) [jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119) [jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134) [jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:524) [jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:319) [jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:253) [jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273) [jetty-io-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95) [jetty-io-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93) [jetty-io-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303) [jetty-util-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148) [jetty-util-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136) [jetty-util-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671) [jetty-util-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589) [jetty-util-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Class org.hibernate.MappingException is not annotated or on the whitelist, so cannot be used in serialization
Serialization trace:
cause (rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException)
throwable (rx.Notification)
```

> Updated

```
public class SomeState  implements LinearState,QueryableState{
    private final UniqueIdentifier uid;
    private final Party partyA;
    private final Party partyB;
    private final List<Address> addresses;



    public SomeState(Party partyA, Party partyB, List<Address> addresses) {
        super();
        this.uid = new UniqueIdentifier();
        this.partyA = partyA;
        this.partyB = partyB;
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }

    public Party getPartyA() {
        return partyA;
    }

    public Party getPartyB() {
        return partyB;
    }

    public List<Address> getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }

    @Override
    public List<AbstractParty> getParticipants() {
        return Arrays.asList(partyA,partyB);
    }

    @Override
    public PersistentState generateMappedObject(MappedSchema schema) {
        if (schema instanceof SomeStateSchema) {
            return new SomeStateSchema().new PersistentSomeState(uid.getId(), partyA.getName().toString(), partyB.getName().toString(), addresses);

        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognised schema $schema");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<MappedSchema> supportedSchemas() {
        return ImmutableList.of(new SomeStateSchema());
    }

    @Override
    public UniqueIdentifier getLinearId() {
        return uid;
    }

}

public class SomeStateSchema extends MappedSchema {

    public SomeStateSchema() {
        super(SomeStateSchema.class, 1, ImmutableList.of(PersistentSomeState.class));
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "records")
    public class PersistentSomeState extends PersistentState{
        @Column(name = "uid")
        private final UUID uId;
        @Column(name = "partyA")
        private final String partyA;
        @Column(name = "partyB")
        private final String partyB;
        @ElementCollection
        private final List<Address> addresses;
        public PersistentSomeState(UUID uId, String partyA, String partyB, List<Address> addresses) {
            super();
            this.uId = uId;
            this.partyA = partyA;
            this.partyB = partyB;
            this.addresses = addresses;
        }
        public UUID getuId() {
            return uId;
        }
        public String getPartyA() {
            return partyA;
        }
        public String getPartyB() {
            return partyB;
        }
        public List<Address> getAddresses() {
            return addresses;
        }

    }
}

@CordaSerializable
public class Address {
    public final String street;
    public final int pincode;

    public Address(String street, int pincode) {
        super();
        this.street = street;
        this.pincode = pincode;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public int getPincode() {
        return pincode;
    }

}
```

From the controller I call:

```
@GET
    @Path("msas")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<StateAndRef<SomeState>> getMSAs() {
        return rpcOps.vaultQuery(SomeState.class).getStates();
    }
```

FLOW is same as in IOU Example.

```
public SignedTransaction call() throws FlowException {
    // Obtain a reference to the notary we want to use.
    final Party notary = getServiceHub().getNetworkMapCache().getNotaryIdentities().get(0);
    Set<PublicKey> set=  getServiceHub().getKeyManagementService().getKeys();

    //val ourParties = ourKeys.map { serviceHub.identityService.partyFromKey(it) ?: throw IllegalStateException("Unable to resolve party from key") }
    //
    List<Party> parties= new ArrayList();
    for (Iterator<PublicKey> it = set.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                        parties.add(getServiceHub().getIdentityService().partyFromKey(it.next()));
                }

    progressTracker.setCurrentStep(GENERATING_TRANSACTION);
    // Generate an unsigned transaction.
    SomeState someState = new SomeState(getServiceHub().getMyInfo().getLegalIdentities().get(0),otherParty,Arrays.asList(new Address("Yes Street",12532)));
    final Command<SomeContract.Commands.Create> txCommand = new Command<>(new SomeContract.Commands.Create(),
                        someState.getParticipants().stream().map(AbstractParty::getOwningKey).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    final TransactionBuilder txBuilder = new TransactionBuilder(notary).withItems(new StateAndContract(someState, MSAContract.MSA_CONTRACT_ID), txCommand);

    // Stage 2.
    progressTracker.setCurrentStep(VERIFYING_TRANSACTION);
    // Verify that the transaction is valid.
    txBuilder.verify(getServiceHub());

    // Stage 3.
    progressTracker.setCurrentStep(SIGNING_TRANSACTION);
    // Sign the transaction.
    final SignedTransaction partSignedTx = getServiceHub().signInitialTransaction(txBuilder);


    FlowSession otherPartySession = initiateFlow(otherparty);

    // Stage 4.
    progressTracker.setCurrentStep(GATHERING_SIGS);
    // Send the state to the counterparty, and receive it back with their signature.
    final SignedTransaction fullySignedTx = subFlow(
                        new CollectSignaturesFlow(partSignedTx, Sets.newHashSet(otherPartySession), CollectSignaturesFlow.Companion.tracker()));

    // Stage 5.
    progressTracker.setCurrentStep(FINALISING_TRANSACTION);
    // Notarise and record the transaction in both parties' vaults.
    return subFlow(new FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx));
}
```

I finally found the rootException:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.den.managment.state.Address, at table: SomeStateSchema$PersistentSomeState_addresses, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(addresses)]
        at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:455)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:422)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.Collection.validate(Collection.java:310)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:333)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
        at net.corda.node.services.persistence.HibernateConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(HibernateConfiguration.kt:101)
        at net.corda.node.services.persistence.HibernateConfiguration.makeSessionFactoryForSchemas(HibernateConfiguration.kt:74)
        at net.corda.node.services.persistence.HibernateConfiguration.access$makeSessionFactoryForSchemas(HibernateConfiguration.kt:27)
        at net.corda.node.services.persistence.HibernateConfiguration$sessionFactoryForSchemas$1.apply(HibernateConfiguration.kt:54)
        at net.corda.node.services.persistence.HibernateConfiguration$sessionFactoryForSchemas$1.apply(HibernateConfiguration.kt:27)
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source)
        at net.corda.node.services.persistence.HibernateConfiguration.sessionFactoryForSchemas(HibernateConfiguration.kt:54)
        at net.corda.node.services.persistence.HibernateConfiguration.sessionFactoryForSchema(HibernateConfiguration.kt:48)
        at net.corda.node.services.schema.HibernateObserver.persistStateWithSchema(HibernateObserver.kt:41)
        at net.corda.node.services.schema.HibernateObserver.persistState(HibernateObserver.kt:37)
        at net.corda.node.services.schema.HibernateObserver.persist(HibernateObserver.kt:31)
        at net.corda.node.services.schema.HibernateObserver.access$persist(HibernateObserver.kt:20)
        at net.corda.node.services.schema.HibernateObserver$1.call(HibernateObserver.kt:27)
        at net.corda.node.services.schema.HibernateObserver$1.call(HibernateObserver.kt:20)
        at rx.internal.util.ActionSubscriber.onNext(ActionSubscriber.java:39)
        at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onNext(SafeSubscriber.java:134)
        ... 42 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Your flow is throwing various exceptions because of underlying issues with your code. Corda is then trying to serialise these exceptions to send them back to your RPC client via the RPC framework. Since these types are not whitelisted to be sent via RPC, you get a Kryo exception when you try.

In other words, these exceptions are just a symptom (of your underlying code throwijng `AnnotationException` or `MappingException`) rather than a root cause.

Can you post the code showing the `Person` state definition and how you are trying to retrieve it from the vault in the flow?

Comment: done as requested. let me know in case you want the flow as well.

Comment: I'm still struggling here :) Could you zip up your CorDapp and share it somewhere? Delete the `build` folders first to reduce bulk - it shouldn't be more than 10MB all in.

Comment: I found the root cause. Though there are still some issues. I wasn't able to make a state queryable too much onus. so I just made it a linear state and was able to commit. now when I do rpcOps.vaultQuery(SomeState.class).getStates(); 



I get the same error.
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Class org.hibernate.AnnotationException is not annotated or on the whitelist, so cannot be used in serialization
Serialization trace:
exception (net.corda.core.utilities.Try$Failure)
How to go about it?

Comment: @Kid101 Please find a way to share the code if you can. I can't debug this remotely.